# Xamarin.Forms app to fit screen ratio of Samsung Galaxy S8

Tags: xamarin.forms

How do I configure a Xamarin.Forms app to fill out phones with newer aspect ratios like the Samsung Galaxy S8?

Currently my Xamarin.Forms app looks like the one on the left below. What configuration do I need to change?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a VerticalOptions FillAndExpand on the outer container, if using Xamarin.Forms. Maybe post a bit of related code or markup.

Comment: It's a vanilla Xamarin Forms app, the screenshot above is just an example I got off the web.

Comment: Same issue here. It seems to be an issue with Xamarin itself.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, I thought this might have been an issue with Xamarin. However, after further research I found it to be a new configuration for Android apps in general to support the 18:9 aspect ratio.

[Here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html) is the Android Developers Blog post describing the updates:

> In order to take full advantage of the larger display formats on these
>   devices, you should consider increasing your app's maximum supported
>   aspect ratio. To do so, simply declare an `android.max_aspect`
>   `<meta-data>` element in the app's `<application>` element:
>
> ```
> <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
> ```

This resolved the issue for me. Related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43628048/140910).

Comment: I'm confused, I've created an emulator AVD with 18:9 aspect ratio to try and test the issue but my app seems to expand to the full length even before I've added the android.max_aspect. Does this apply to emulators? Is there a way I can test to see the problem first before seeing that `android.max_aspect` fixes the problem?

Comment: @ThibaultD. I'm not sure. I own a Samsung Galaxy S4 and S8 so I am able to test the scenario on physical devices.